# ScrollTo doesn't link to correct li

Tags: jquery

I have implemented a scroll to on my test site and added a Specialities option to the menu of my site but once clicked it doesn't seem to display the correct content. Rather than displaying Specialities content it is displaying Expertise

http://global-markets-recruitment.com/test/

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/wp-content/themes/child/script/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/wp-content/themes/child/script/jquery.backgroundPosition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/wp-content/themes/child/script/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/wp-content/themes/child/script/jquery.cycle.lite.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/wp-content/themes/child/script/jquery.accordian.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#contentGallery').cycle({
                fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed">

<div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#home" class="goto_home"></a>
            <h1>
                Global Markets Recruitment</h1>
        </div>
<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="end"><a href="#contact" id="navContact" class="goto_contact"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#specialities" id="navSpecialities" class="goto_specialities"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#context" id="navContext" class="goto_context"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#artScience" id="navArtScience" class="goto_artScience"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#home" id="navHome" class="goto_home"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="navPointer">
            <div id="controlContainer">
                <div id="pointer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentHolder">
        <div id="contentGallery">
            <img src="Images/Gallery/london.jpg" width="1200" height="550" alt="London" />
            <img src="Images/Gallery/singapore.jpg" style="display: none;" width="1200" height="550"
                alt="Singapore" />
            <img src="Images/Gallery/geneva.jpg" style="display: none;" width="1200" height="550"
                alt="Geneva" />
        </div>
        <div id="contentShadow">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="contentScroller">
                <div id="home" class="page">
                    <div class="homeContent">
                        <span class="homeHeaderText">GMR</span>
                        <div class="clear">
                        </div>
                        <div class="homePageText">
                            <p>
                                Global Markets Recruitment is an expert in financial recruitment.
                </p> 
<p>Through leveraging our extensive networks and combining this with the latest recruitment practices, credibility and professionalism we find our strategic clients the most capable and intelligent candidates throughout Europe, the United States, Asia and the Middle East.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div id="artScience" class="page">
                    <div class="pageContent">
                        <span class="headerText">About Us</span>
                        <div class="pageText">
                            <a class="acc_trigger_3" href="#">About Global Markets Recruitment</a>
                            <div class="acc_container">
                                <p>
                                    Our philosophy is simple, we stick to our strengths. We understand where and how we can make a difference. We ensure that before engaging with your organisation and the assignment we appreciate how this relates to both the long and short term value of your business and our role in achieving this.
The approach is not just professional, but personal. We employ both empathy and understanding into the recruitment process. This can only be done by gaining a thorough understanding through face-face meetings with both clients and candidates, allowing us to appreciate their unique aspirations and exacting criteria.</p>
                            </div>
<div class="seperator">
                            </div>
                            <a class="acc_trigger_3" href="#">Clients</a>
                            <div class="acc_container">
                                <p>
                                    When working with a company, we employ a very rigorous approach. Our selection process consists of screening a pool of qualified candidates. We identify applicants from various sources based on systematic research and the Global Markets Recruitment database, through which we would entirely map the market of potential candidates in various institutions across the globe. We would also utilise our extensive professional networks and relationships, complemented with our vast experience in the recruitment space. This approach saves you a great deal of time by restricting the number of candidates you consider. 
When approaching a potential candidate they are approached in the most discrete, confidential and at the same time compelling way, also taking into account their plausible concerns in relation to the career opportunity at hand.</p>
                            </div>
<div class="seperator">
                            </div>
                            <a class="acc_trigger_3" href="#">Candidates</a>
                            <div class="acc_container">
                                <p>In turn we offer candidates that work with us intellectually challenging and financially rewarding positions with the most dynamic, and ambitious organisations throughout Europe, the United States, Asia and the Middle East.</p>
                            </div>
</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="context" class="page">
                    <div class="pageContent">
                        <span class="headerText">Approach</span>
                        <div class="pageText">
                                    During the identification phase we would have first introductory telephone interviews.</p>
<p>During the selection phase we shall conduct personal and detailed interviews with motivated and rigorously qualified candidates.</p>
<p>This would ultimately result in the shortlist of applicants who on the basis of the defined job specification qualify for the position. They should meet the profile requirements to a large extent and should, in meetings with you, make the impression of being outstanding candidates, willing to accept the role on offer. Candidates will be presented by means of standardised curriculum vitae, detailed confidential report including all base salary, bonus and benefits.</p> 
<p>Finally, we would assist at the offer stage and with the integration of the successful candidate into the client.</p>                     
</div>
</div>
</div>
                <div id="contact" class="page">
                    <div class="pageContent">
                        <span class="headerText">Expertise</span>
                        <div class="pageText">
                            Content coming soon
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div id="specialities" class="page">
                    <div class="pageContent">
                        <span class="headerText">Specialities</span>
                        <div class="pageText">
                            Content coming soon...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you at least give us a hint on where the event is bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because they both link to #contact. Change last a #contact to #specialities.

```
        <ul>

            <li class="start"><a href="#home" class="goto_home">Home</a></li>

            <li><a href="#artScience" class="goto_artScience">About Us</a></li>

            <li><a href="#context" class="goto_context">Approach</a></li>

            <li><a href="#contact" class="goto_contact">Expertise</a></li>

        <li><a href="#contact" class="goto_contact">Specialities</a></li>

        </ul>
```

Also your container is not big enough to contain all the section and #specialities goes on a new "row". Floats under #home

Comment: Thank you. The scrollto effect doesn't seem to work for Specialities. Any ideas?

Comment: in your scripts.js you don't seem to have hook for Specialities

Comment: #contentScroller {
width: 100000px;
}